# Problems with JWplayer

Tags: flash, video, html5-video, jwplayer, jwplayer7

I am having several problems getting the embedded JW player 7 to work.

When I set "primary":"html5" (or leave it as a default) the player works in every browser except IE/Edge
in IE/Edge the message "This text will be replaced with a player." is displayed.

When i set "primary":"flash" 
- It works in FIrefox
- In chrome it loads for a moment then says flash plugin failed to load
- In IE/Edge it says "This text will be replaced with a player".

The filetype is mp4

### This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script>jwplayer.key="NDoNxIXotd5wGBwjdgAuzLKrr4Wpt3jhOQgPgA==";</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="myDiv">This text will be replaced with a player.</div>
<script>

jwplayer("myDiv").setup({
"file": "videos/WEB_INTRO_1.mp4",
"image": "images/P1090566.JPG",
"height": 360,
"width": 640,
"primary":"flash"
});

jwplayer().on('ready', function(e) {
jwplayer("myDiv").play();
});


</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you post a demo link and/or copy any errors displaying in your console?

Comment: Any solution to this problem? I'm having the same issue.